# Not able to display collection to half of size of the screen for every device ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

[In Image their is lot os space between the two items of uiCollection view.And they are not display properly for every device size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCXJo.jpg)I am trying to Display collection two items at one row but it doesn't display properly for every devices how can I split screen into two part in  swift.I have use several Constraint but it doesn't work
I also have similar problem for UITableview.

```
import UIKit

class MarketProduct: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchbar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var ItemCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    let productImages:[String]=["pulse","pulse","pulse","pulse","pulse","pulse","pulse","pulse","pulse","pulse","pulse"];
    let productPrice:[String]=["$20000","$20000","$20000","$20000","$20000","$20000","$20000","$20000","$20000","$20000","$20000"]
    let productDescription:[String]=["Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements","Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements","Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements","Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements","Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements","Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements","Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements","Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements","Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements","Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements","Server-side rendering with JavaScript libraries like React is where the server returns a ready to render HTML page and the JS scripts required to make the page interactive. The HTML is rendered immediately with all the static elements"]
    let productAge:[String]=["2 years old","2 years old","2 years old","2 years old","2 years old","2 years old","2 years old","2 years old","2 years old","2 years old","2 years old"]
    let locations:[String]=["pune","pune","pune","pune","pune","pune","pune","pune","pune","pune","pune"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchbar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        searchbar.layer.borderWidth = 1
        searchbar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        searchbar.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        searchbar.layer.masksToBounds = true
 
    }
    
}
extension MarketProduct:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        productImages.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = ItemCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"ItemCell", for: indexPath) as!  Items
        cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(named: productImages[indexPath.row])
        cell.PriceLabel.text = productPrice[indexPath.row]
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = productDescription[indexPath.row]
        cell.itemLocation.text = locations[indexPath.row]
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
//          let height = collectionView.frame.height
//            let width  = collectionView.frame.width
//            return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
//          let height = view.frame.size.height
          let width = view.frame.size.width
      
          // in case you you want the cell to be 40% of your controllers view
        return CGSize(width: width * 0.4, height: 360)

        

    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering collection view leading and trailing is 0 with the view you need to implement the following UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods:

```
extension  MarketProduct: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width/2, height: 360)
    
    }
}
```